# Is there a test-suite for Linux to test a computer?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a test suite that can test as many aspects of the hardware as possible.

I already know about fsck and badblocks.

Answer (score 5):

Phoronix Test Suite, http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can use memtest86 to test your memory, it get's installed as default with ubuntu or is available from http://www.memtest86.com/ it runs outside of the OS since it needs to test without much loaded in memory.  For stress testing the CPU use prime95 from http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [smartmontools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) to test the health of your hard disk drives. It reads the SMART values (monitored inside the HDD) and allows to detect slightly degrading drives before they really produce heavy problems.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [**LBS**](http://lbs.sourceforge.net/) utilities. It is a collection of programs for Linux benchmarking.

Answer (score -3):

http://www.f-secure.com/linux-weblog/2009/09/22/rescue-cd-311/

Check out F-secure. Some basics:

- virus-scanning
- Data / partition handling

It is a live cd which boots and offers you a wide variety of tools to diagnose and solve...

Comment: F-secure's tools are not related to Hardware testing.